# Route's base path for subdirectories

Tags: php, apache, slim, slim-3, fastroute

I have the following structure:

```
/home/
    alvaro/
         public_html/
             Code Playground/
                 SlimTest/
                     logs/
                     public/
                     src/
                     templates/
                     vendor/
                     ...
```

`http://example.com` points to `/home/alvaro/public_html`, thus `http://example.com/Code Playground/SlimTest` points to `/home/alvaro/public_html/Code Playground/SlimTest`, directory on which I've placed this `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In short, loading `http://example.com/Code Playground/SlimTest` in the browser executes my `/home/alvaro/public_html/Code Playground/SlimTest/public/index.php` Slim/3.9.0 (slim/slim-skeleton) entry point.

My problem is that I can't get routes right. I've tried every conceivable combination:

```
$app->get('/Code Playground/SlimTest', …);
$app->get('/Code Playground/SlimTest/', …);
$app->get('/Code Playground/SlimTest/public', …);
$app->get('/', …);
// …
```

... but I always get the *404 Not Found* page delivered by Slim's `NotFound` class.

1. Is there a way to get base path upon route definition so I can prepend it in `get()`?
2. If not, what would a hard-coded path look like?
3. Should I look for a fix in Apache, such as [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)?

Comment: That's because Slim has no clue it's being run from the subdirectory. I would have expected that the latter route "/" worked but alas. Have you tried any of these suggestions: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/1529 ?

Comment: @SketchyCoder After playing around with the information in the GitHub ticket and debugging `\Slim\Http\Uri::createFromEnvironment()` I have a strong suspicion that the feature is built-in and should work out of the box in current version, but it doesn't work for me because of a bug. Slim compares `REQUEST_URI` (URL encoded) with `SCRIPT_NAME` (not encoded) and my actual directory name has a space (`%20` != ` `). Sorry, when redacting names for brevity I never thought spaces would matter.

Comment: No worries! Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @SketchyCoder I've found a couple of ugly workarounds (that mostly involve adding `%20` here and there) but this is getting personal so I'll try to find a proper fix when I have some time. Meanwhile I've edited the question to fix redacted names.

Comment: I officially give up. Every workaround fixes one thing and breaks another. I'll just create separate sites or will use the PHP web server.

Comment: Sorry to hear that! Good luck with the alternative solution

Comment: It is bad practice to put all your web application source code inside public directory.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara Absolutely! But the public directory here is `/home/alvaro/public_html/Code Playground/SlimTest/public/`. Apache doesn't serve files from `/home/alvaro/public_html/Code Playground/SlimTest/logs` or `/home/alvaro/public_html/Code Playground/SlimTest/src`; not even `/home/alvaro/public_html/Code Playground/SlimTest`.